# generalized $\chi^2$-distribution - expectation value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chi-squared

I'm currently encountering a generelized $\chi^2$-distribution in my calculations.

I found the pdf of it online, but nothing given for the expectation value or anything else.

At the moment I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$\dot{c}(t)=\int_0^t\mathrm{d}t_1Q(t-t_1)c(t_1)$

Here, $Q(t-t_1)=iY(t-t_1)+X(t-t_1)$

and $X(t-t_1)$ and $Y(t-t_1)$ have generalized $\chi^2$-distribution for each $t-t_1$.

How do i solve this, are there any approaches?

Thanks!

(The pdf I talked about is given by $f(x; k,\sigma_1^2,\ldots,\sigma_k^2) = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{e^{-\frac x {\sigma_i^2}}}{\sigma_i^2 \prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^k \left(1- \frac{\sigma_j^2}{\sigma_i^2}\right)} \quad\text{for } x\geq0$)

Comment: So what are you talking about?  I mean, what's the pdf, or the formula, or the definition, or characterization, or even what's the URL?  If I told you the answer was a generalized gamma function, would that please you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The pdf is given on the wikipedia-article  about the generalized $\chi^2$ distribution. Because I can't solve (or dont have any clue on how to handle it) the differential equation, I thought it would be usefull to, at first, look at the expectation value of the given terms. I thought that there was a closed formula- but i didn't find it.

Comment: That article is pretty vague, and has more than one formula for the p.d.f. If you believe you are talking about the version discussed in the first paragraph under "definition", the expectation  is $\operatorname{tr}(AB)$. Going by the third paragraph, the expectation is $\operatorname{tr}(CD)+e$.